# App only visible for android 2.1 and 2.2?

Tags: android

Hi I have a problem with my app. It is only visible for Android 2.1 and 2.2.
Here is my manifest `android:anyDensity="false"` is because I am resizing images.
I have tried my app on almost all Android version from 2.1 to 4.0 and it worked, but it's not visible on Google Play on any newer version then 2.2 or it says that is not compatible.

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="15"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" android:required="false"/>
<supports-screens  android:anyDensity="false"/>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentations](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html):

*android:anyDensity
    Indicates whether the application includes resources to accommodate any screen density.*

*For applications that support Android 1.6 (API level 4) and higher, this is "true" by default and you should not set it "false" unless you're absolutely certain that it's necessary for your application to work. The only time it might be necessary to disable this is if your app directly manipulates bitmaps (see the Supporting Multiple Screens document for more information).*

Therefore, it should be set to true.

```
<supports-screens  android:anyDensity="true"/>
```

Comment: solved, i added <supports-screens  android:anyDensity="true" and moved resource files(images) to nodpi folder.

Answer (score 0):

```
<supports-screens android:resizeable="true"
                        android:smallScreens="true"
                        android:normalScreens="true"
                        android:largeScreens="true"
                  android:anyDensity="true"></supports-screens>
```

Add this in your manifeast file

Comment: But when i set anydensity to true it resizes images alone. I do that in my code myself ?

Comment: but when i set anydensity to true. It resizes images that i do not want to resize.i do that myself in code

Answer (score 0):

Remove the android:required="false" from the uses-permission tag. You're not supposed to place this inside a permission tag, but in a uses-feature tag... Anyway, WAKE_LOCK will not need any required declaration:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```